# What's the problem with redirect loop?

Tags: language-agnostic

I look at this site
http://3.7designs.co/blog/2007/12/advanced-css-menu-trick/

and clicking on demo http://www.3point7designs.com/web-design2.html

both google chrome and firefox can't access it because of direct loop. What's that ? Then how to do redirect the right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a rule configured on your server which keeps sending HTTP 301 Redirects to the same page for every request. While I don't actually know what might be the cause of this without knowing your webserver and application configuration, the most likely cause is that you try to redirect / normalize URLs (e.g. to enforce the leading `www` on the host or something similar) but you don't have a proper condition in place to let the final request pass your rule unnoticed instead of triggering it. An example would be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.3pointdesign.com [R=301,L]
```

This rule applies to all requests whether the request has a leading www or not. Thus this constitutes a redirect loop. It can be fixed by adding a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.3pointdesign.com [R=301,L]
```

It checks if the current request is for the `www.3pointdesign.com` host and only proceeds to the `RewriteRule` if not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's not my server I was curious to know why :). Weird they didn't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A redirect loop is usually where PageA redirects automatically to PageB and PageB automatically redirects to PageA, thus an endless loop of redirects.